# What does "broadcast/multicast datagrams undelivered" in netstat indicate?

Tags: networking, udp, freebsd, netstat

I'm diagnosing an UDP packet loss issue in FreeBSD. `netstat -s -p udp` has the following output:

```
udp:
        116974545 datagrams received
        0 with incomplete header
        0 with bad data length field
        0 with bad checksum
        198 with no checksum
        6313 dropped due to no socket
        119696 broadcast/multicast datagrams undelivered
        41534 dropped due to full socket buffers
        0 not for hashed pcb
        116807002 delivered
        955 datagrams output
        0 times multicast source filter matched
```

Although most of the output is straight forward, I'm really confused about what does `broadcast/multicast datagrams undelivered` indicate. Is that the total number of undelivered multicast packets? Or does that refer to the number caused by a specific reason, like `drooped due to full socket buffers` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"broadcast/multicast datagrams undelivered"` indicates total number of received multicast/broadcast UDP packets with no socket willing to accept them. The counter is bumped in two cases:

[Case #1](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/sys/netinet/udp_usrreq.c#536) -- accounts for all/most of undelivered UDP multicast/broadcast packets in your case:

```
531            /*
532             * No matching pcb found; discard datagram.  (No need
533             * to send an ICMP Port Unreachable for a broadcast
534             * or multicast datgram.)
535             */
536            UDPSTAT_INC(udps_noportbcast);
```

[Case #2](http://bxr.su/FreeBSD/sys/netinet/udp_usrreq.c#598) would also bump "dropped due to no socket" counter which is probably not your situation.

```
596        UDPSTAT_INC(udps_noport);
597        if (m->m_flags & (M_BCAST | M_MCAST)) {
598            UDPSTAT_INC(udps_noportbcast);
599            goto badunlocked;
600        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what's the difference between these two cases. Does case #2 a special case of case #1? Did case #1 means I lost packet due to not joining some multicast group?

Comment: If destination IP address is M/Bcast then only case #1 is possible. Case #2 would only happen if dest IP is *not* a broadcast/multicast, yet has M_BCAST or M_MCAST flag set. That seems to be possible only in case where a packet was received with a layer-2 broadcast/multicast address (e.g Ethernet), but with non multicast/broadcast dest IP.